# How to traverse through text in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I'm trying to make a typing speed test counter. The goal is to move the blinking cursor throughout the text only if the correct character is entered. I'm unable to understand how to move through the text. I shall then count the number of minutes taken and calculate wpm.

```js
function timer() {
  var seconds = 3;
  var element = document.getElementById('timer');
  var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

  function countdown() {
    if (seconds == -1) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      element.innerHTML = "Time Up";
      var value = 1;
      wpm();
    } else {
      element.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + seconds + " " + "seconds";
      seconds--;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.title-of-page>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.title-of-page {
  background-color: #414a4c;
  color: #ced3db;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #46494f;
}

a {
  color: green;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #878f9b;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.typing-field {
  width: 60em;
  height: 8em;
  background-color: #7e7e7f;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin-left: 15em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

#display-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.user-input {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 35em;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

#timer {
  padding-top: 4em;
  padding-left: 10em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}

.typed-cursor {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  color: black;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron title-of-page container-fluid">
    <h1>Typing Counter</h1>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navigation-bar container-fluid">
    <div class="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Leaderboard</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <div id="timer">
      <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="timer();">Start</button>
    </div>
    <div class="typing-field">
      <p id="display-text"><span class="typed-cursor">T</span>his is to test your typing speed. So type like you'll never type again.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="user-input">
      <input type="text" name="user-input-text-box" id="user-input" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

For javascript I tried to do something like this. It's mostly wrong. I'm still a beginner.

```
window.onload = function wpm() {
  var text = document.getElementById('user-input').innerHTML;
  var i=0;
  document.getElementById('user-input').onkeyup = function() {
    var letter = this.value;
    if(letter==text[i])
    {
      letter.style.color="green";
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what problem are you getting? 
Maye also basic idea behind your solution? 
Are you struggling with implementation or with a design decision? 

Be more specific and it will be easier to get help. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling with the implementation. I do not know how to modify the text(as in traverse through it using the blinker) by checking if the user enters the correct input.

Comment: You don't have control over the cursor placement within a `<textarea>` or `<input>` element without inserting content. So if you want to "advance the cursor one character" you would have to change the value of the DOM element. You **should investigate the `contenteditable` DOM attribute** and use a `<div>` for this purpose.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The way I understand the code, the cursor he talks about is within the `<div class="typing-field"><p>`, so it's not a `textarea` or `input`. You can run the snippet to see the "blinking" letter.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Comment: All I get with the snippet is a runtime error: `cannot find wpm` - so didn't waste time investigating that.

Comment: it seems more complicated since it isn't just a `<div>` tag, but a `<div><p>` with a `<span>` that apparently would need to be removed and replaced during each character addition. Would this be correct?

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with after playing a little with your code:

```js
var display = document.getElementById('display-text');
var userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');

userInput.onkeyup = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < userInput.value.length; i++) { // Counts correct letters
    if (display.innerText[i] != userInput.value[i])
      break; // Exit loop if incorrect
  }
  display.innerHTML = '<span style="color: green;">' + display.innerText.substr(0, i) + '</span>' + '<span class="typed-cursor">' + display.innerText.substr(i, 1) + '</span>' + display.innerText.substr(i + 1);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.typing-field {
  width: auto;
  /* Modified for snippet */
  height: auto;
  /* Modified for snippet */
  background-color: #7e7e7f;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin-left: 0;
  /* Modified for snippet */
  margin-top: 0;
  /* Modified for snippet */
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

#display-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.user-input {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 0;
  /* Modified for snippet */
  padding-top: 0;
  /* Modified for snippet */
}

#timer {
  padding-left: 0;
  /* Modified for snippet */
  padding-top: 0;
  /* Modified for snippet */
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}

.typed-cursor {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  color: black;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="timer">
      <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="timer();">Start</button>
    </div>
    <div class="typing-field">
      <p id="display-text"><span class="typed-cursor">T</span>his is to test your typing speed. So type like you'll never type again.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="user-inputs">
      <input type="text" name="user-input-text-box" id="user-input" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This code compares the displayed and the typed strings, highlights in green the correct letters and put the blinking cursor on the one to be typed.

I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the letters typed and then turn them a different color, you can save the text string in a variable and queue through it dumping the typed letters into another array, then merge them together into the output field:

```js
    let textToType = "This is what I want you to type.";
    const typedLetters = [];

    document.getElementById('user-input').addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      const key = event.which || event.keyCode;
      const nextLetter = textToType[0].charCodeAt();
      const outputTarget = document.getElementById("display-text");
      
      const greenWrapper = document.createElement("span");
      greenWrapper.classList.add("typed-cursor");

      if (key === nextLetter) {
        typedLetters.push(String.fromCharCode(nextLetter));
        textToType = textToType.substr(1);
        greenWrapper.textContent = typedLetters.join("");
        outputTarget.textContent = textToType;
        outputTarget.prepend(greenWrapper);
        
        
      };
    })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.title-of-page>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.title-of-page {
  background-color: #414a4c;
  color: #ced3db;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #46494f;
}

a {
  color: green;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #878f9b;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.typing-field {
  width: 60em;
  height: 8em;
  background-color: #7e7e7f;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin-left: 15em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

#display-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.user-input {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 35em;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

#timer {
  padding-top: 4em;
  padding-left: 10em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}

.typed-cursor {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  color: black;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="jumbotron title-of-page container-fluid">
    <h1>Typing Counter</h1>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navigation-bar container-fluid">
    <div class="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Leaderboard</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <div id="timer">
      <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="timer();">Start</button>
    </div>
    <div class="typing-field">
      <p id="display-text">This is what I want you to type.
    </div>
    <div class="user-input">
      <input type="text" name="user-input-text-box" id="user-input" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems easy enough - can you put this in a snippet?

Comment: @RandyCasburn sure thing

Comment: Er. If you start by typing "dqsdqsT", the T becomes correct. And it stays correct even if you delete it! I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @TakitIsy I was just trying to show him how to solve the problem the question asked, not solution the whole thing.